# Connectedness vs path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connections

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

We say that $X$ is locally connected if there is a basis of $\tau$ consisting of open connected sets; we say that $X$ is locally path-connected is there is a basis of $\tau$ consisting of open path-connected sets.

Suppose we have a set $X$ which is locally path-connected.  Then are connected components and path-connected components the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in a locally path-connected space, the path-components coincide with the connected components. That follows since in a locally path-connected space, the path-components are open.

Comment: Are the path-components also closed?

Comment: I just realized it by myself:  its complementary is made of path-connected components, which are open, so it is open.

Comment: So the proof is the following.

If $p$ is a point of $X$, its connected component $C_p$ contains its path-connected component $P_p$ (because a path-connected is connected).  But $P_p$ is non empty ($p$ belongs to it) and is clopen, so it has to be $C_p$, otherwise $C_p$ wouldn't be connected.  Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: You are the only one clever enough to choose the user-name "User" LOL

Comment: @user254665 Ahah, thank you :)